# Problems from Editable (EditText) to Integers

Tags: android, casting, android-widget, android-edittext, parseint

I am having problems getting the integer values for a simple math program out of the edittext boxes. I can get a string out of it but when I try to convert it to a integer it crashes. I have tried:

```
int a = Intger.parseInt(X2.getText().toString());
```

and it still crashes. Any idea's would be greatly appreciated.
Here is source code.

```
package siu.edu.cs215;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class Quadratic extends Activity {
private TextView answer;
private EditText X2, X, K; 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quad);
    Button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.quad);
    Button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backwards);
    answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.B1);
    X2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.xsquared);
    X = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.xcoeff);
    K = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kconst);

}
public Button Button1 = null;
public Button Button2 = null;
public void QA (View view){
//double sol1=0.0, sol2=0.0, disc=0.0;
int a = Integer.parseInt(X2.getText().toString());
//int b = Integer.getInteger(X.getText().toString());
//int c = Integer.getInteger(K.getText().toString());
//disc = Math.pow(b, 2) - 4.0*a*c;
//sol1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2.0 * a);
//sol2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2.0 * a);
answer.setText(a);
};
public void BACK (View view){
Intent i = new Intent(this, ExtraCreditActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >




<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6" >

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/xsquared"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="X^2 +"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/xcoeff"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="X + "
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/kconst"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/quad"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="QA"
            android:text="Quadratic" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".8" >

            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2pt"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backwards"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:onClick="BACK" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you made sure that you get a valid string?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're problem is in trying to parse an empty string.  Perhaps you can simply avoid performing any calculations unless all fields can be correctly parsed.  Put your parsing into a try/catch block.

Comment: "It crashes" is not very helpful. Please provide the logcat snippet of the crash.